# SQL : Returning records with more than one match

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table which I want to return records which have more than one BSID.

Example:

```
FirstName   LastName   CustomerID
A           Apple      12345
AB          Orange     12451
AC          Durian     44123
BODY        SHOP       11223
BODY        SHOP       11224
BODY        SHOP       11225
```

Question:

How do I return only the bottom three where this particular individual has three different customer ID?

I have tried writing

```
select Firstname, lastname, BSID, count(*)
from table Profile
group by firstname, lastname, BSID
having count(*) > 1
```

but the result return all the 6 rows.

Comment: what have you done so far? (on your own)

Comment: What is a BSID?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the subquery you already wrote to identify first/last name pairs you want to retain and then join this back to your main table.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Profile t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT FirstName, Lastname, BSID
    FROM Profile
    GROUP BY FirstName, Lastname, BSID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.Firstname = t2.Firstname AND
       t1.Lastname = t2.Lastname   AND
       t1.BSID = t2.BSID
```

Answer (score 0):

In Amazon Redshift, if you include **BIS** also in **group by** clause, then it will return all the values. Since on **grouping with BIS**, there is no duplicate records. Below would be the resultset, which you will be receiving,

```
FirstName   LastName   CustomerID   Count
A           Apple      12345        1    
AB          Orange     12451        1
AC          Durian     44123        1
BODY        SHOP       11223        1
BODY        SHOP       11224        1
BODY        SHOP       11225        1
```

And you are checking condition in having clause as count(*) > 1. So all the rows will satisfy this condition.

But your required result would be like below,

```
FirstName   LastName   Count
A           Apple      1    
AB          Orange     1
AC          Durian     1
BODY        SHOP       3
```

Hence you have to modify your query as below,

```
select Firstname, lastname, count(*)
from table Profile
group by firstname, lastname
having count(*) > 1
```

Just remove BIS from "**Select**" and "**Group by**" clauses.

Hope this should solve your problem.